# Widgets Position not Fixed in APK file

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I am new to kivy and  i am very confuse to set the position of the widgets for mobile apllication

As i am using default size of the desktop window screen, In that widgets position look goods and in a proper allignment

i have attached PNG file of  window screen and mobile screen

but when i use this in  android apk file and installed in mobile, then all position of widgest are messed up and not looks to good for visibillity

so how to adjust the size and postion of widgets for android apk file

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

KV = ('''
<LOGIN_Window>:
    name: 'login_window1'
    FloatLayout:
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'permit me'
            elevation: 10
            pos_hint: {"left": 1, "top": 1}
    
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Welcome to permit me'
            font_size: '35sp'
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.21, 'y': 0.65}
            size_hint_y: '0.35dp'
            size_hint_x: '0.50dp'
                              
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 0.65}
            size_hint: None, None
            size_hint: '0.6dp', '0.08dp'
    
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Email-ID'
                font_size: '15sp'
                height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(10)
    
                MDTextFieldRound:
                    id: login
                    hint_text: 'For Eg:- XXY...@gmail.com'
                    icon_left: "email"
                    input_type: 'text'
    
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                pos_hint: {'x':.25, 'y':4}
                spacing: '50dp' 
    
                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    id: logIn
                    text: 'Login'
    
    
                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: 'Register'
    
            MDLabel:
                text:'Powered By Technology'
                pos_hint : {'x': 0,'y': 0}
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(10)


WindowManager:
    LOGIN_Window:
              '''
      )


class LOGIN_Window(MDScreen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: First of all 'left' is an invalid `pos_hint` key. Also, `size_hint` is supposed to be within 0 and 1, which may not work as intended if combined with `dp`, `sp` etc. These may affect the relative position and size of the layouts/widgets on the window resulting in cluttered or overlapped widgets.

Comment: Right , as ApuCoder mentioned , pos_hint is the relative position that the widget will appear on screen. From range 0 to 1 , which represent the percentage ( 0 —> 0% ; 1 —> 100% )  sth like this. E.g. pos_hint(0.5, 0.7) ; for x-coordinate of the screen , the widget will be placed at half of the screen width ; y-coordinate : will be placed at ( screen height * 0.7 ) ; and I think the “left” can be replaced by “x”  ?

Comment: Thank you so ApuCoder and Paul Lam  i understand where i getting wrong in code